# How can I use request.query to get a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, express

In my client-side code, I called getContents():

```
$.getJSon("/getContents", function(room){
  theRoom=$("#roomName").val();//textarea's value
...
});
```

In getContents(), which is in the server-side code(index.js), how can I use request.query or any other function to get theRoom(variable) so that I can get the contents of a Room based on its title(theRoom)?

getContents();

```
var getContents=function(req,res){
...
var room=?
...
roomCollection.findOne({name: room}, function(err,theRoom){...
  res.send(theRoom)
});
...
}
```

Comment: What does the index.js file look?

Comment: Can Someone help me out? I'm still struggling with it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve a variable using request.query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469073/how-to-retrieve-a-variable-using-request-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the results of your JSON, the following might be a good start:

```
$.getJSON("/getContents", function(data){
  var theRoom=$("#roomName").val();//textarea's value
  $.each(data.rooms, function( key, room) {
    if(room.title == theRoom)
       alert(room); 
  });
});
```

Comment: getContents() sends a room not the entire collection. The problem is how to send room that has the same name as theRoom. I'll update the question to show getContents()

Comment: you could send the requested room name to the server and do some server side querying

Comment: How do I do that? I'm kind of new in Web applications