# How to retrieve a variable using request.query

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my client-side code, I called getContents():

```
$.getJSon("/getContents", function(room){
  theRoom=$("#roomName").val();//textarea's value
...
});
```

In getContents(), which is in the server-side code(index.js), how can I use request.query or any other function to get theRoom(variable) so that I can get the contents of a Room based on its title(theRoom)?

getContents();

```
var getContents=function(req,res){
...
var room=?
...
roomCollection.findOne({name: room}, function(err,theRoom){...
  res.send(theRoom)
});
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it as a request param to [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) using

```
$.getJSON("/getContents", {
    room: $("#roomName").val()
}, function (room) {
    //rest of code
});
```

Note: not sure about the serverside syntax to read the request parameter, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089582/how-to-get-url-parameter-in-express-node-js)